# How to connect 2 Lists into 1 Model

Tags: linq, list, object

I work with LinqToSQL and sadly I have to work with Data from 2 different Databases in 2 different Locations.

So I will get my List of User with "Username" and "UserID".
And I will get my List of Groups  with "UserID" and "GroupID" and "GroupName"

I have 1 User and for each User I have X groups.

How to join this both lists, so I can have an object with:
UserID, Username, GroupID, Groupname

My code so far:

```
        //Mappinglist
        List<Group_ADUser_Mapping> mapList = (from a in dc.Group_ADUser_Mappings select a).ToList();
        //Userlist aus Mappinglist
        List<ADUser> userList = (from a in dc2.ADUsers select a).ToList();
        //Gruppenname aus Mappinglist
        List<Group> groupList = (from a in dc.Groups select a).ToList();

        //Zusammenführen
        IEnumerable list3 = from u in mapList
                            join ud in userList
                            on u.EmployeeNumber equals ud.employeeID
                            join g in groupList
                            on u.GroupID equals g.IDPK
                            select new
                            {
                                UserID = u.EmployeeNumber,
                                Username = ud.name,
                                GroupID = u.GroupID,
                                Groupname = ud.Groupname
                            };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you can simply perform a join via linq

assuming list1 and list2 as your existing collections containing the mentioned properties

example

```
IEnumerable list3 = from u in list
                    join ud in list2
                    on u.UserID equals ud.UserID
                    select new
                    {
                        UserID = u.UserID,
                        Username = u.Username,
                        GroupID = ud.GroupID,
                        Groupname = ud.Groupname
                    };
```

list3 will now contain objects having the desired properties

Comment: NIce, I hoped for such an easy solution, will try it later and accept or comment it! Thx man

Comment: share your list structure. example is based on assumption on IEnumerable of some object having mentioned properties.

Comment: could you also share class structures for `Group_ADUser_Mapping`, `ADUser` & `Group` ?

Comment: No, that are linq objects from my database... enough to know the fields I think...

Comment: Ok, know my mistake, the on x and on y was different types (string and int)